# Allow 'crontab -l -u' for non-root users

Tags: sudo, cron, users

I have two users: user1 and user2
user1 is added to /etc/cron.allow
But when I run `crontab` with the `-u` option, I get :

```
user1@hostname:~$ crontab -l -u user2
must be privileged to use -
```

Is it possible to grant this `crontab -u` permissions for a user without giving him sudo rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grant `sudo` access to just that particular command. For example, the following rule...

```
testuser1     ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/crontab -l -u *
```

Would let `testuser` run `crontab -l -u <someuser>`.  E.g, these all work:

```
[testuser1@fedora ~]$ sudo crontab -l -u testuser1
no crontab for testuser1
[testuser1@fedora ~]$ sudo crontab -l -u testuser2
no crontab for testuser2
[testuser1@fedora ~]$ sudo crontab -l -u root
no crontab for root
```

But other commands fail:

```
[testuser1@fedora ~]$ sudo crontab -l
[sudo] password for testuser1:
Sorry, user testuser1 is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/crontab -l' as root on fedora.
[testuser1@fedora ~]$ sudo date
[sudo] password for testuser1:
Sorry, user testuser1 is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/date' as root on fedora.
```

Etc.

To grant these permissions to multiple users, consider creating a group (e.g., `cronpeople`), and then using that in your sudoers configuration:

```
%cronpeople     ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/crontab -l -u *
```

You can replace `%cronpeople` with `ALL` if you want **all** users to have these privileges.